# FOSUserBundle : Redirect the user after register with EventListener

Tags: redirect, symfony, fosuserbundle, event-listener

I want to redirect the user to another form just after registration, before he could access to anything on my website (like in https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/387).

So I create an eventListener like in the doc :

```
<?php
namespace rs\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection at the end of the password resetting
 */
class RegistrationConfirmedListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => 'onRegistrationConfirmed'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirmed()
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('rsWelcomeBundle_check_full_register');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Services.yml :

```
services:
    rs_user.registration_completed:
        class: rs\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmedListener
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

But it doesn't work, the user register, he click on the confirmation link in his mailbox, he is not redirected on the page I want, he is logged and I just have the message who said the account is confirmed.

Why it doesn't redirect me to the route : rsWelcomeBundle_check_full_register  like I want ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your `src/robStorm/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` file?

Comment: I just add it in my previous message, thanks in advance !
I also try with the IMPLICIT_LOGIN event but no way to get the event and use a setResponse method on it...

Comment: And it's rs, not robstorm, it was a mistake ;) Always no way to do something correct with these events...

Comment: For consistency rename RegistrationConfirmListener to RegistrationSubscriber

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To accomplish what you want, you should use `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM` instead of `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED`.

You then have to rewrite rewrite your class `RegistrationConfirmedListener` like:

```
class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('rsWelcomeBundle_check_full_register');

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

And your `service.yml`:

```
services:
    rs_user.registration_complet:
        class: rs\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

`REGISTRATION_CONFIRM` receives a `FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent` instance as you can see here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php

It allows you to modify the response that will be sent: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Event/GetResponseUserEvent.php

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The problem was also I don't use the parameter of type : GetResponseUserEvent.
It works great, but is there a way to display the page who said "Your account is confirmed...etc" and after redirect the user to my page ?
Thanks ;)

Comment: If you want to first show "Your account is confirmed...etc" then you shouldn't use this method but rather override the template `Registration/confirmed.html.twig` and add some js that redirects the user after XX seconds.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ;)
I also have another question about event : What event I have to use to set a specific role after registration ?

Comment: You would probably have better to do this in the constructor of your entity. If not, then I think the best event would be REGISTRATION_COMPLETED

Comment: **For future readers if you use the HWIOAuthBundle, ATTENTION :** "the HWIOAuthBundle does not use the FOSUserBundle registration controller so it will never fire those events." [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493324/hwioauthbundle-fosuserbundle-events-not-firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493324/hwioauthbundle-fosuserbundle-events-not-firing) ;)

Comment: For me (using FOSUserBundle & HWIOAuthBundle) , only `REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` works like expected.

Answer (score 6):

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.x-dev",
```

Not sure why the accepted answer works for you as **REGISTRATION_CONFIRM** happens after the token is confirmed.

In case you want to perform an action, redirect to another page with some additional form after the FOS **registerAction** I would suggest the following way.

This is the code that is performed on **registerAction** once the submitted form is valid by FOS:

#### FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController

```
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }
```

As you can see the first possible return happens after **FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS** event **in case the response is null** which in my case doesn't as I have configured a mailer to send a confirmation token and FOS is using an listener that listens to this **FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS** event and after sending an email it sets a redirect response.

#### FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\EmailConfirmationListener

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
    );
}

/**
 * @param FormEvent $event
 */
public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
{
    /** @var $user \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface */
    $user = $event->getForm()->getData();

    $user->setEnabled(false);
    if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
        $user->setConfirmationToken($this->tokenGenerator->generateToken());
    }

    $this->mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);

    $this->session->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());

    $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_check_email');
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}
```

## Okay I understand! So how do I redirect to another page?

I would suggest to overwrite **checkEmailAction** as most likely you don't want to overwrite the listener that sends an email as that's part of your workflow.

Simply:

#### TB\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController

```
/**
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function checkEmailAction()
{
    /** @var UserManager $userManager */
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var string $email */
    $email = $this->get('session')->get('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');

    $user = $userManager->findUserByEmail($email);

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('wall', ['username' => $user->getUsername()]));
}
```

As you can see instead of rendering FOS's **check_email** template I decided to redirect user to his new profile.

Docs how to overwrite an controller: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html (basically define a parent for your bundle and create a file in the directory with the same name as FOS does.)

Comment: How to pass array from registration controller to onRegistrationSuccess method of EventListener??

Comment: event is a data transfer object. so when u dispatch it ($dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);) Don't use arrays to move data around.

Comment: I want to pass the query string parameter array from controller to onRegistrationSuccess method as I've to save that data into database. Is there any other way to get the query string data in onRegistrationSuccess??

Comment: from top of my head, this is the event u are dispatching right? "new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response)", so onRegistrationSuccess($event), retrieve the string from $event like... $event->getRequest() or something and then persist it in DB.

Comment: Thanks man, got it. But in controller, I can get all query string parameters from `$request->query->all()` in the form of array and as per your previous comment, I've to get that from `$event->getRequest()->server->get('HTTP_REFERER')` in form of string. So is there any better solution??

Comment: shame i don't have access to the codebase, but I believe they are the same Request objects, so whatever u can get in controller ->query->all() u should be able to do also as event->getRequest()->query->all() no?

Answer (score 3):

Route redirection can also be used:

```
fos_user_registration_confirmed:
    path: /register/confirmed
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: redirection_route
        permanent: true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using a confirmation email, you can redirect the user right after submiting the registration form this way :

```
class RegistrationConfirmationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var Router */
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'onRegistrationConfirm'];
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirm(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var RedirectResponse $response */
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $response->setTargetUrl($this->router->generate('home_route'));
    }
}
```

The subscriber declaration stay the same :

```
registration_confirmation_subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\Subscriber\RegistrationConfirmationSubscriber
    arguments:
        - "@router"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution: you can also override the route. Let's say you want to redirect to your homepage you can do something like this:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 * @Route("/", name="fos_user_registration_confirmed")
 * @Template(":Default:index.html.twig")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
```

Comment: Please argue how this (if it works - don't claim any knowledge re. symfony) is valuable in addition to correctly specifying `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM` as per [cheesemacfly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16428009/3789665).

Comment: @greybeard it works by overriding the route: instead of being redirected to the default FOSUSER page, you are redirected to the page you have chosen (here the index route).

Comment: @KunwarSiddharthSingh You should explain more in details what you want to achieve specifically. Have a look at the previous answers or at the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html

Comment: @Tons_1 Thanks for comment. Actually I am working on shopping cart and I want when user come in Cart page and click on register via FosUser user then redirect on same cart page rather than after registration redirect on home page .