# HWIOauthBundle & FOSUserBundle events not firing

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I have followed all of the advice found [here](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697) for setting up the HWIOAuthBundle with the FOSUserBundle, but I wish to be able to access the events fired when a user registers and so far seem unable to do that.  Having followed the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427267/fosuserbundle-redirect-the-user-after-register-with-eventlistener), here is my event subscriber (note that I am not interested in all of the events, but I just wanted to test if any of them were being fired):

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ClientBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger;

/**
 * RegistrationConfirmListener
 */
class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    private $logger;

    function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router, Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE => 'onRegistrationInit',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM    => 'onRegistrationConfirm',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED  => 'onRegistrationConfirmed',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED  => 'onRegistrationCompleted',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS    => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationInit(UserEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info('Registration has started: ' . serialize($event));
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info("Registration is confirming: " . serialize($event));
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirmed(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info("Registration has been confirmed: " . serialize($event));
    }

    public function onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info("Registration has been completed: " . serialize($event));
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info("Registration has been successful: " . serialize($event));
    }
}
```

And here is my service definition:

```
acme_user.registration_complete:
    class: Acme\ClientBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
    arguments: [ @router, @logger ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

However I cannot see any of the FOSUserEvents being logged, even though the authentication/registration is successful.  The only other information I have that I feel may be relevant is that I am also integrating the FOSUserBundle with then SonataAdminBundle, which also seems to be working correctly.  (Well, correctly once I figured out how to upgrade the FOSUserBundle to v2.0 and fixed the changes required.)

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing here to be able to hook into these events?

Comment: Do you have other services that are being properly loaded?  Is there a chances that your services.yml file is not being loaded?  Does app/console container:debug show your service?

Comment: Yes, the service is being loaded and I can see it when I run container:debug, but thanks for the extra debugging tip

Comment: Is the code you posted your real code or did you edit it for your question?  I ask because your constructor only shows one argument.  It should have thrown an error message.  Do you have error_reporting(E_ALL); somewhere?  Do simple typos throw an error for you?

Comment: I did edit the code for my question as the router is not used yet, I have added this back in

Comment: Well.  I don't see anything else wrong as far as event handling.  Maybe stick a die statement in onRegistrationInitialize.  It's possible that the logger is not properly initialized and thus your log messages are not being persisted.

Comment: Just gave this a try and no luck

Comment: And you are testing this by going through the FOSUserBundle registration process?  You have not overridden the registration controller?  If you put a die statement in you listener's constructor does it die?  Running your test in development mode?  Kind of scraping the bottom of the barrel here.

Comment: In order: no, I am going through the HWIOauth registration process, no, yes and yes.

Comment: Well.  When all else fails try deleting app/cache/dev.  You mentioned going from FOSUserBundle 1.x to 2.x.  Maybe you are somehow still accessing the S1.x registration controller.  Maybe put a die statement in the S2 registration controller.  Maybe try dispatching an event from a different controller completely.  Maybe make a functional test or symfony command.  It's going to be something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the HWIOAuthBundle does not use the FOSUserBundle registration controller so it will never fire those events.

Comment: Did you find any HWI OAuth events that can be listened?

Comment: Sorry, there aren't any that I could find