# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle FOSUserEvents

Tags: events, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to do redirection after regiter like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427267/fosuserbundle-redirect-the-user-after-register-with-eventlistener), but my onRegistrationConfirm() Event function is not executed during the registration. My code is similar to that in answer. I just don't know is there is something more to do, to make my event working. I'm new to symfony, so it might be really easy.

Comment: Do you import the `services.yml` in the main `config.yml` file?

Comment: I have edited post, becouse I was wrong - getSubscribedEvents() is called, but my event is not. 
And yes... I have services import in config.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK...so 
I guess theere is no such thing as FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM, there is nothing about it [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php). But I found there REGISTRATION_SUCCESS event which is exectly what I was looking for.

So my code looks this:

```
class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
private $router;

public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess'
    );
}

public function onRegistrationSuccess(\FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent $event)
{
    $url = $this->router->generate('my_route');
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}
}
```