# Symfony 2 : FOSUserBundle : Using FOSUserEvents for Redirection

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have implemented FOSUserBundle in my Symfony 2 project to manage my members. Each time a form is successfully filled (registration, changing password...) I redirect the user to my homepage. To do this I use the SUCCESS events provided by the bundle (see the documentation : [Hooking into the controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md)).

It works fine for CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS and PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS events but it doesn't work for the FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS event. I am not redirected after user registration (the default bundle 'show profile' page is displayed). **EDIT :** (the default bundle 'check email' page is displayed as the option registration confirmation by email is enabled).

I have implemented this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312927/symfony2-fosuserbundle-fosuserevents).

Can someone help me to understand why ? My code here below:

Thank you for your help.

**The listener :**

```
<?php

// src/FBN/UserBundle/EventListener/FormSuccessListener.php

namespace FBN\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection when a form is successfully filled
 */
class FormSuccessListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onFormSuccess',    // Not working
            FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS => 'onFormSuccess', // Working
            FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS => 'onFormSuccess',    // Working                   
        );
    }

    public function onFormSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('fbn_guide_homepage');

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

**The service :**

```
services:
    fbn_user.formsuccess_listener:
        class: FBN\UserBundle\EventListener\FormSuccessListener
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Are you using the email confirmation?

Comment: @Qoop Yes I do. To be precise, I would like to avoid the redirection to the registration confirmation page and to display a flash message on my homepage.

Comment: So after you confirm via email and then it takes you to the registration confirmation page? The event you should be listening to in this case would be the `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM` but this does take a `GetResponseUserEvent` rather than a `FormEvent` so you should deal with that accordingly. (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L116-L117)

Comment: Not exactly. When you register with a validated form, you are redirected to a page that says that an email has been sent. At this time, I would like to redirect the user to my homepage and display a flash message (an email has been sent...). The method confirmAction() of the RegistrationController is used later when the user confirms by clicking the link of the email. So I think that the correct event is REGISTRATION_SUCCESS.

Comment: Ah right. It is probably that the email confirmation listener is being called after your listener meaning that the response is being set again due to the order that they were added to the dispatcher later. Changing the priority so that yours comes after the FOS listener may sort it, so `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => array('onFormSuccess', -10),`

Comment: I think you are right. I suppose that the email confirmation functionality  (set or not in config.yml) depends in fact of the activation / deactivation of the email confirmation listener  [FOSUserBundle/EventListener/EmailConfirmationListener.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/EmailConfirmationListener.php). As you said, the redirection is also set in this listener but probably after mine. I try it after work and confirm this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm the solution proposed by [Qoop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791606/qoop) in the 5th comment of the main post.

As the registration confirmation by email is enabled, the email confirmation listener is used. This listener sets a response on `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` after my own listener. So I had to change the priority of my listener in order to set the response :

**So here is the modified listener :**

```
// src/FBN/UserBundle/EventListener/FormSuccessListener.php

namespace FBN\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection when a form is successfully filled
 */
class FormSuccessListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => array('onFormSuccess',-10),
            FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS => array('onFormSuccess',-10), 
            FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS => array('onFormSuccess',-10),                        
        );
    }

    public function onFormSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('fbn_guide_homepage');

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hooking the wrong event.
According to what I've found in the [RegistrationController of FosUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L68), you have to subscribe to `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` event.

Comment: Thank you, but I think i'm using the correct event as it works for the two others events. All controllers have the same structure. So look at lines 57 to 66 : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L57. Moreover, the documentation says : 'Thus, all SUCCESS events allow you to set a response if you don't want the default redirection. and all COMPLETED events give you access to the response before it is returned.'

Comment: COMPLETED events use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent for the listener method. This class does not contain a setResponse() method. SUCCESS events use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent that contains a setResponse() method.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L65), the controller is always redirecting to the `fos_user_registration_confirmed` after the event your are hooking to. so...

Comment: Yes, but first, this code tests if the $response attribute of the event is  null (see line 63). The listener permits to catch the event (a FormEvent instance see line 58) and to set the redirection before the controller does (line 64/65). So if the $response attribute of the event is not null, the default redirection is not setted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think the right answer is in the doc

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html

Registration success listener with enabled confirmation at the same time¶

When you have registration confirmation and you want to hook up to FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS event you will have to prioritize this listener to be called before FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\EmailConfirmationListener::onRegistrationSuccess:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => [
            ['onRegistrationSuccess', -10],
        ],
    ];
}
```

**If you don't do it, EmailConfirmationListener will be called earlier and you will be redirected to fos_user_registration_check_email route.**