# FosUser, redirect after registration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

So, i'm trying to change the redirection url after registration with FOS.

So, i have create a custom `RegistrationConfirmListener` :

```
<?php
namespace project\ApplicationBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection at the end of the password resetting
 */
class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('myUrlForRedirect');

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

And add these lines into my `services.yml` :

```
rs_user.registration_complet:
        class: ThanksWho\ApplicationBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

But when i test, i'm always redirected to `/confirmed` and not to `myUrlForRedirect`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427267/fosuserbundle-redirect-the-user-after-register-with-eventlistener, more info there

Answer (score 0):

I think you omitted to import the `GetResponseUserEvent` class in your listener. You should replace the `use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;` by `use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;`

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem.

I forget to add :

```
public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
```

in my BundleClass...