# RegistrationConfirmListener & FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, event-listener

I trying to redirect new user to welcome page after register using Listeners. But i have no results. I do like says in that page [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427267/fosuserbundle-redirect-the-user-after-register-with-eventlistener). Please help. Here is the code:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection at the end of the password resetting
 */
class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('_welcome');

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

And my service:

```
<service id="acme_user.registration.confirmed" class="Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener">
        <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
        <argument type="service" id="router"/>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to use  `REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` instead `REGISTRATION_CONFIRM`. And all works.