# How to add a check during the login process with Symfony FOS User

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

my symfony app works with dynamics subdomain, and my users can login only on their subdomain.
If user George is a user of subdomain `test` (he has the subdomain as a field) he can login on test.myapp.com. But during the login process I would like to check his subdomain like FOS User check the password, if the account is activated ... and stop the login process if the user is not on the right subdomain.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FOS 2.0, events are available for you to hook into and add custom logic like this.  Symfony provides the `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents` and FOS has `FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents`.  Using the onImplicitLogin should give you access to what you need.

For a nice example of linking for a FOS event, see [cheesemacfly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427267/fosuserbundle-redirect-the-user-after-register-with-eventlistener).

If you have trouble, I can write the listener and the service you need.

Comment: I'll try be myself and I'll give you a feedback ! Thanks !