# How do I redirect to a dynamic custom route after register with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've been looking for a while for this, but can't find the answer.

## Expected behavior:

- User goes on a product page
- User wants to buy the product, so he needs to login / register (with a modal)
- User doesn't have an account so he registers
- After registration (there is no email confirmation), user is signed in and redirected to the current product page
- User can proceed to checkout, *etc*...

This behavior is working in the case of a login, with the use of the `_target_path` parameter in the form.

However, **this parameter does not apply in registration**. This is kinda annoying, where did I miss something out ? I am looking into implementing a Listener on the registration success event but it seems really odd to not being as simple as for the login form.

### Edit: found my solution, see my own answer below

Comment: This should work implementing a Listener on `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` and changing the response to redirect to wished page.

Comment: The login form use the framework session feature to save the current path and redirect it automatically after login. The registration controller is out this default behavior.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I will post my listener for further people wondering. Glad to put an end to my research :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering for those wondering too.

## TL;DR : the registration process does not follow the login's

Thanks to @yceruto for the comment.

I made a quick listener on the `REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` event:

```
/**
 * @param FormEvent $event
 */
public function redirectOnRegistration(FormEvent $event)
{
    $route = $event->getRequest()->headers->get('referer', $this->router->generate('homepage'));
    $response = new RedirectResponse($route);
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

(I redirect on homepage if there is no referer).

Answer (score 0):

In your security settings you must turn on referer:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|console)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/any_pattern
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: any_pattern_login
            check_path: any_pattern_login
            use_referer: true
        logout: true
        access_denied_handler: app.security.access_denied_handler
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.api_authenticator
            provider: api_provider
        logout:
            path: any_pattern_logout
            invalidate_session: true
```

Comment: that's for the login form, not the register.

Comment: ah, ok. have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427267/fosuserbundle-redirect-the-user-after-register-with-eventlistener?answertab=votes#tab-top